# codeigniter route with method and edit

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm in trouble with a codeigniter route,

I need to do this:

```
method/:any = method/index_function
method/edit/:any = method/edit_function
```

I wrote this in the route config file:

```
$route['method/:any'] = 'method/index';
$route['method/edit/:any'] = 'method/edit';
```

But don't want works.

Any suggestions?

---

resolve!

I change the order of the line in the route file:

```
 $route['method/edit/:any'] = 'method/edit';
 $route['method/:any'] = 'method/index';
```

thanks to Basheer Ahmed

Comment: method/:any = method/index_function

method/edit/:any = method/edit_function

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones. [Codeigniter Routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

```
$route['method/edit/(:any)'] = 'controller/edit';
$route['method/(:any)'] = 'controller/index';
```

Comment: i wrote in my config file this:

$route['dog/:any'] = 'dog/index';
$route['dog/edit/any'] = 'dog/edit';

but don't works

Comment: Try using round paranthesis around `any` and then try

Comment: What happens when you try `dog/1`

Comment: if I user dog/1 works, but if I try dog/edit/1 I have a 404 error

Comment: thanks! it's works! the problem was the order of the line!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, your route key can not have the same name as an existing controller, because CodeIgniter will check for a Controller first, and if it finds one, it will try to call the method in that controller. Please try:

```
$route['m/:any'] = 'method/index';
$route['m/edit/:any'] = 'method/edit';
```

Comment: i wrote in my config file this:

$route['dog/:any'] = 'dog/index';
$route['dog/edit/any'] = 'dog/edit';

but don't works

Comment: Can you please define by what you mean "it don't work"? Do you get an error message? If not, do you have error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors turned on? I am not exactly sure, but try to wrap the :any in (parenthesis)

Comment: i have a 404 error! and I try to add brackets, but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to apply parenthesis basically. Codeigniter routing really works great. Here is an example how I achieved the same in my project :

```
$route['listnote/stepone/(:any)']='listnote/listnote/loanInformation';
```

Comment: These `()` are not callled brackets but rather parenthesis.. :)